# Want to implement edit field using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

static for page

The jQuery code

```
$('#edit').click( function() {
    var tr = $(this).parent();
    var new_row = '<tr class="new_row"><td><input type="text"></td><td><input type="text"></td><td><input type="text"></td><td><input type="text"></td><td><input type="text"></td></tr>';
    tr.replaceWith(new_row);
});
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: please consider adding HTML also

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Aq8jB/

Comment: edit is not working.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Final Updated fiddle => http://jsfiddle.net/Aq8jB/5/

:)

Use following

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#addButton").click(function (e) {
        $("#table_dynamic").submit(function() {
    var inputVal= $("#first_name").val();
    var characterReg = /^([a-zA-Z0-9]{1,})$/;
    if(!characterReg.test(inputVal)) {
        $("#first_name").after('<span class="error">Maximum 8 characters.</span>');
    }
});
        var n=1;
        var n1 = $("#first_name").val();
        var n2 = $("#company").val();
        var n3 = $("#email").val();
        var n4 = $("#contact_no").val();
        var n5 = $("#remarks").val();
    if(n1!="") {
    if(n2!="") {
    if(n3!="") {
    if(n4!="") {
    if(n5!="") {
        $("#table_dynamic").append('<tr><td>'+n+'</td><td id="fname">' + n1 + '</td><td id="cmpny">' + n2 + '</td><td id="emailid">'+ n3 + '</td><td id="phno">'+ n4 + '</td><td id="rmark">'+ n5 + '</td><td><input class="deleteButton" type="button" value="Delete" name="Delete"/><input id="edit" type="button" value="Edit" onClick="edit()"></td></tr>');
    }
    else {
        alert("Remarks cannot be Empty");
    }
    }
    else {
        alert("Contact cannot be Empty");
    }
    }
    else {
        alert("Email cannot be Empty");
        var atpos=n3.indexOf("@");
var dotpos=n3.lastIndexOf(".");
if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length)
  {
  alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
  return false;
  }

    }
    }
    else {
        alert("Company cannot be Empty");
    }
    }
    else {
        alert("Name cannot be Empty");
    }
});
    $(document).on("click", ".deleteButton", function (e) {
        var target = e.target;
        $(target).closest('tr').remove();

    });
     $(document).on("click", "#edit", function(e) {
        alert($(this).attr("id"));                      
        var tr = $("#edit").parent();
        alert(tr);
        var new_row = '<tr class="new_row"><td><input type="text" value="'+$("#fname").text()+'"></td><td><input type="text" value="'+$("#cmpny").text()+'"></td><td><input type="text" value="'+$("#emailid").text()+'"></td><td><input type="text" value="'+$("#phno").text()+'"></td><td><input type="text" value="'+$("#rmark").text()+'"></td></tr>';

        tr.replaceWith(new_row);

    });

    $("#clear").click(function (e) {
        $("#first_name").val('');
        $("#company").val('');
        $("#email").val('');
        $("#contact_no").val('');
        $("#remarks").val('');
    });



    });
});//]]>  

</script>
```

And Console error has gone ,You properly use logic to Edit field ,there was console error.

Updated

```
     $(document).on("click", "#edit", function(e) {
    //  alert($(this).attr("id"));                      
        var tr = $("#edit").parent();
//      alert(tr);
        $("#fname").html('<input type="text" value="'+$("#fname").text()+'">');
        $("#cmpny").html('<input type="text" value="'+$("#cmpny").text()+'">');
        $("#emailid").html('<input type="text" value="'+$("#emailid").text()+'">');
        $("#phno").html('<input type="text" value="'+$("#phno").text()+'">');
        $("#rmark").html('<input type="text" value="'+$("#rmark").text()+'">');     

        var new_row = '<tr class="new_row"><td><input type="text" value="'+$("#fname").text()+'"></td><td><input type="text" value="'+$("#cmpny").text()+'"></td><td><input type="text" value="'+$("#emailid").text()+'"></td><td><input type="text" value="'+$("#phno").text()+'"></td><td><input type="text" value="'+$("#rmark").text()+'"></td></tr>';

        //tr.replaceWith(new_row);

    });
```

Comment: But it should edit the existing fields.... not create new fields.... Existing fields should be converted to textboxs....

Comment: ok i m coding. you didnt code for it , I am doing

Comment: Its the same.... existing fields are not edting..oly new fields are entered/?

Comment: You dont want , labels at the left side of Txtbox ? I mean values are coming to the textboxes

Comment: okie....then have to add edit function to edit button to update the row ryt?  NOw only values are here after editing?

Comment: I updated fiddle, Is this what you want? :)

Comment: Yes ,values are coming , Now Can you do next Coding ,Like if Text boxes are coming and Then Do wat you want on click of Final Click of Final EDIT button please?

Comment: Welcome ,now you know what to do :) dont u?

Comment: i would add the update function and replace the values of new  txtbox to the row......

Comment: did you check updated fiddle ? If it satisfies your requirement ,then please mark as correct ans.

Comment: yeah marked..... can i call the add function itself so that i can avoid seperate validation?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Aq8jB/7/  Can your please check why the addbutton func is not working in edit .....i have give the same id but not working...

Comment: ok , Can you please create Another Question,I will answer you there.

Comment: :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23193040/update-function-in-jquery-table?noredirect=1#comment35474253_23193040

Comment: PRATIK :dude help me with that??

Comment: Yes sure. wait now i m in office ,see u later

Comment: take a look at that as soon as possible...

Comment: pratik : Its kinda iporatant.... can u look quickly..

Comment: I Answered your Question :) Yoooo !!

Comment: Do Select it as Best ans if it satisfies your requirement :)

Comment: i would but the mail validation is still missing..is there any function to delete all row onclick?

Comment: Should i do it for you ? :) Can you please create another Question ? :)

Comment: Hello i think You make the comment on This Question , lets play there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23193040/update-function-in-jquery-table/23197166#23193040

Comment: its really imp can u do tat alone?

Comment: please elaborate what your problem is now about validation.

Comment: its only checking for empty box...mail valid is nt checking.... And also is there a function to delete all rows in table ?

Comment: Ok ,i m working on First email validation, for both Options

Comment: Prathik : Have you found the bug???